# Dropdowns not loading dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

*I am trying to populate 3 dropdowns dynamically.*
On the selection on one dropdown, the other dropdowns will be filled with the options.

I am using `javascript` to achieve this, and it's working fine.
But the **problem is, it's working fine in `jsFiddle`, but not working when I am using it in my application**.
I am developing the application with `angular Js & materialize front-end framework`.

**Code :**

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    Select Country: <select name="state" id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Main Cartegory</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    Select State: <select name="countrya" id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select Country first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    Select District: <select name="district" id="districtSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select State first</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
var stateObject = {
    "MEN": {
        "Top Wear": ["T-Shirts", "Casual Shirts","Formal Shirts","Suits"],
        "Bottom Wear": ["Jeans", "Casual Trousers","Formal Trousers"],
        "SPORTS & ACTIVE WEAR":["", ""],
        "Footwear":["Casual shoes","Formal Shoes"]
    },
    "WOMEN": {
        "Top Wear": ["T-Shirts", "Casual Shirts","Formal Shirts","Suits1"],
        "D2": ["d21", "d22"]
    },
    "KIDS": {
    "E1":["e11", "e12"],
    "E2":["e21", "e22"]
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        districtSel = document.getElementById("districtSel");
    for (var country in stateObject) {
        countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
    }
    countySel.onchange = function () {
        stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        districtSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        for (var state in stateObject[this.value]) {
            stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
        }
    }
    countySel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        districtSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        var district = stateObject[countySel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < district.length; i++) {
            districtSel.options[districtSel.options.length] = new Option(district[i], district[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Why are you developing an AngularJS app without using anything AngularJS related?

Comment: My web-application contains angular js code, but for the drop-down, I am using javascript.

Comment: Why? Why not use angular directives like `ng-change` and `ng-repeat` which facilitate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Okay, so how can I accomplish my requirement using suggested directives?